# Почему RecycleView уходит за границу экрана?

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview

Ниже разметка. Все высоты элементов, кроме собственно Recycler и constraintlayout, указаны в явном виде и оставшегося места на экране должно хватать. Тем не менее, часть списка уезжает под экран. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stock_bgnd"
    tools:context=".PoActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/action_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMsgPortfolio"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Портфель пуст"
        android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRemainingAssets"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chAddAssets"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chAddAssets"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chDelAssets"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="204dp"
        android:text="Удалить"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/dark_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSelected"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="не выбран"
        android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/chAddAssets"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.727"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lvAssets" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chAddAssets"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="204dp"
        android:text="Добавить"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/dark_gray"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvSelected" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvAssets"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chDelAssets">

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="ГРУППА:"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.126"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chAddAssets" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLoaded"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvGroupName" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Я поставил 0dp и получил белый экран. Видимо, кому пора за одну парту со мной. Вопрос остается открытым.

Comment: Читайте как работает разметка. Указывать явную высоту для `View` - это плохая идея. `0dp` нужно понимать как применять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы установка высоты 0dp растянула виджет в каких-либо границах, а не скрыла его, нужно для начала указать эти самые границы, попробуйте дополнительно привязать RecyclerView к нижней части окна

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

И затем измените высоту на 0dp

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я так и сделал.